# How to convert OpenXML WordprocessingDocument to Word Interop's Document in C#

Tags: c#, office-interop, openxml-sdk

I need to generate an invoice in pdf format, using docx template, provided by a customer.

Presently I use WordprocessingDocument object of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging, save it as docx

```
 byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(tempFolderLocation + "\\" + fileName);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
                WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);
                File.WriteAllBytes(fileLocation + Filename + ".docx", stream.ToArray());
            }
            wordDocument = OpenWordDocument(fileLocation + Filename + ".docx");
```

and then convert it to pdf using some executable. I want to improve the performance and was thinking of converting WordprocessingDocument to Word Interop's Document and then saving it as pdf, using SaveAs2 method, but I am too new to C# to be able to do it on my own, so any help will be appreciated.

N.B. I have checked some 3rd party products as Spire.Doc for Net, but found they don't render docx to pdf properly as Word Interop does (the docx template is a combination of  header, footer, tables and images). In case of Spire, for example, their support team has acknowledged there is an issue and raised a ticket for a fix.

Comment: The docx file is a "interop" document. Are you saying you're looking for interop code to open and convert/save a Word document? There are lots of code samples "out there" for that. But this shouldn't be done server-side...

Comment: How to load and save as pdf using Word Interop I know. I also know how to save my OpenXml to docx. But it means I have to save the invoice as docx first and then load it using Word Interop and then SaveAs2 as pdf. I want to avoid it and just "handle" OpenXml object I have to Interop, if possible and then to save it as pdf.

Comment: Word doesn't support "streaming", but it is possible to write the Open XML in the OPC Flat File format to a (empty) Word document using Range.InsertXML. That would be your only option without saving to a file. Otherwise you'll need a third-party software that can convert to PDF. Or save to docx then use Word Automation Services (part of SharePoint) for the conversion.

Comment: Thank you, @Cindy Meister. Can I trouble you for an example, or perhaps a link where I can find one, please?